# No route matches [POST] "/auth/facebook/callback" Omniauth-facebook - Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

Almost same questions but with the `Get` requests are asked (which probably show that they wanna do something after login - but things apart , actually i configured my application according to [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-devise-and-omniauth-for-your-rails-application) tutorial and when i made request from the [Google Postman Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) using the `localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback` It gave me following error

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST]
>   "/auth/facebook/callback"):

In my **devise.rb**

```
  config.omniauth :facebook,  'key', 'abc_secret',{ :scope => 'email' }
```

In my **User Model**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable,
         :trackable, :validatable, :registerable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
```

In my **routes.rb**

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
```

The above route is defined according to [devise_token_auth](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/devise_token_auth/0.1.37) . And when I do the `rake routes` It shows me only following routes related to amniauth

```
                auth_failure  GET    /auth/failure(.:format)                  callbacks#omniauth_failure
                              GET    /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)       callbacks#omniauth_success
                              GET    /omniauth/:provider/callback(.:format)   callbacks#redirect_callbacks
             omniauth_failure GET    /omniauth/failure(.:format)              callbacks#omniauth_failure
                              GET    /auth/:provider(.:format)
```

You can see that these are all `Get` requests so server's complaint makes sense (as usual ) but why `devise` didn't made it . and how to accomplish it

In my **GemFile**

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth'

gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-digitalocean'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

Note: It may be of any worth to mention that This App is actually a `rails_api application`

Comment: what exactly is the problem? That you're not using Google Postman correctly? Everything else looks okay.

Comment: @sevenseacat Thanks for downvote , but the problem is that how to make call to facebook/login using devise

Comment: okay, that's a different question. Have you tried just linking to the provider path as specified in your routes?

Comment: @sevenseacat dear i mentioned the call  in the question - kindly guide me to correct provider path if it's wrong

Comment: Omniauth (& Oauth) uses a GET request for the callback - not POST. You are using the wrong request method in Postman. There really is not much more to it.

Comment: @max dear , firstly i've to send request to facebook , which will allow me to sign_in through facebook . That the matter in this question

Comment: Yeah and its not via POST. I have implemented omniauth several times - you are just doing it wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-omniauth

Comment: @max dear , you're right , it'd be via get request . Kindly post :P your comment as answer and If possible then a little more detail also . so that other can take advantage of it